# Android pass data from fragment to dialogfragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle, android-dialogfragment

i manage to pass some data from fragment to dialog fragment , i using bundle to implement passing data function. but the problem is i keep get the null value in my dialog fragment even when i debug the program is already showing that my bundle contain the data already. is it i can't use bundle to passing the data or my way to using bundle is wrong.

**MainActivity**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Fragment {

Button test;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View h = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    test = (Button) h.findViewById(R.id.test);
    test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("key", "asdasdasdasd");
            FragmentDialog newFragment = new FragmentDialog();
            newFragment.setArguments(args);
            newFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "TAG");
        }
    });
    onOpenDialog();
    return h;
}


public void onOpenDialog()
{
    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentDialog overlay = new FragmentDialog();
    overlay.show(fm, "FragmentDialog");
}
```

}

**FragmentDialog**

```
 public class FragmentDialog extends DialogFragment
{

private SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager viewPager;
TextView textView;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    //dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.YELLOW));
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    return dialog;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, container);

    // tab slider
    sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    viewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
    textView =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textview);

    Bundle mArgs = getArguments();
    String myValue = mArgs.getString("key");
    textView.setText(myValue);
    return view;
}


public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0)
        {
            // find first fragment...
            Fragment_Tab_1 ft1 = new Fragment_Tab_1();
            return ft1;
        }
        if (position == 1)
        {
            // find first fragment...
            Fragment_Tab_2 ft2 = new Fragment_Tab_2();
            return ft2;
        }
        else if (position == 2)
        {
            // find first fragment...
            Fragment_Tab_3 ft3 = new Fragment_Tab_3();
            return ft3;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 2 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "First Tab";
            case 1:
                return "Second Tab";
            case 2:
                return "Third Tab";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why are you calling  `onOpenDialog();` in `onCreateView()` ????

Comment: @BurhanuddinRashid onOpenDialog(); is to call the prompt up message from my dialogdragment

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

In your MainActivity:

```
FragmentTransaction transection=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                FragmentDialog mfragment=new FragmentDialog ();
               //using Bundle to send data
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("key","asdasdasdasd");
                mfragment.setArguments(bundle); //data being send to SecondFragment
                transection.replace(R.id.frag, mfragment);
                transection.commit();
```

In onCreateView of FragmentDialog:

```
String myStr = getArguments().getString("key");
        text.setText(myStr);
```

Comment: thanks, it cant work, my getArguments still get with null value

Answer (score 1):

you can use newInstance static  methode:

```
public static FragmentDialog newInstance(int someInt) {
    FragmentDialog yourFragmentDialog = new FragmentDialog();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("intVariable", someInt);
    args.putString("stringVariable", someString);
    yourFragmentDialog.setArguments(args);

    return yourFragmentDialog;
}
```

and then to get the data:

```
getArguments().getInt("intVariable", 0);
```

Hope that it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
public void onOpenDialog()
{
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("key", "KEY_FROM_OPEN_DIALOG");
    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentDialog overlay = new FragmentDialog();
    overlay.setArguments(args);
    overlay.show(fm, "FragmentDialog");
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry. It's not clear for me. It it helped you or not?

Comment: thanks it no work, my getArguement still get with null value